# Angular 5 & Go Webservices

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, angular5

Angular 5 as a front end & backend as Golang and written Services in go 
When the page is refreshed, the request is sent to the server which results in a page not found 404 error since the request bypasses the router in angular.

Ex: From Routing if we call /login we are able to display a page but if refresh the same it is showing as page not found 404.

Angular5:

```
const AppRoutes: Routes = [
          { path: '/', component: SignupComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'login' , component: LoginComponent },
          { path: 'home' , component: VisitsComponent},
          { path: 'createavisit/:id', component: VisitComponent},
      ];
```

go:

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./angular/dist")))
    http.HandleFunc("/register", RegisterHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/log", LoginHandler)
```

Could someone help me to fix this issue

Comment: In app module file where you import routing module add useHash:true parameter. For example: RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk Great! I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app module file where you import routing module add useHash:true parameter. For example: RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})